# How to duplicate rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My Table datas:

```
ID      |   PRODUCT_NAME | QUANTITY
1       |   PRODUCT_1    | 3
2       |   PRODUCT_2    | 2
3       |   PRODUCT_3    | 1
4       |   PRODUCT_4    | 3
5       |   PRODUCT_5    | 6
6       |   PRODUCT_6    | 7
7       |   PRODUCT_7    | 10
8       |   PRODUCT_8    | 15
9       |   PRODUCT_9    | 12
10      |   PRODUCT_10   | 25
```

When I make select query I need the result:

```
1       |PRODUCT_1
1       |PRODUCT_1
1       |PRODUCT_1
2       |PRODUCT_2
2       |PRODUCT_2
3       |PRODUCT_3
4       |PRODUCT_4
4       |PRODUCT_4
4       |PRODUCT_4
5       |PRODUCT_5
5       |PRODUCT_5
5       |PRODUCT_5
5       |PRODUCT_5
5       |PRODUCT_5
5       |PRODUCT_5
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please include the details of your question in the question as text and not attached as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table and insert into it integers from 1 to 25.

```
CREATE TABLE INTEGERS ( N INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO INTEGERS VALUES (1), (2), ... (25);
```

Now you can join this to your table like follows:

```
SELECT id, product_name
FROM MyTable
JOIN INTEGERS ON MyTable.quantity >= INTEGERS.N
```